# SSIS Package behaving strangely when running through agent but fine from BIDS on the same server

Tags: ssis

My package runs correctly from BIDS but when I schedule it to run from SQL Agent, it fails with the following error message.

Message
Executed as user: STRW067029\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.5500.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:00:36 AM  Error: 2013-07-31 11:00:45.39     Code: 0xC000F427     Source: Envoy Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: To run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:00:36 AM  Finished: 11:00:45 AM  Elapsed:  9.282 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am using same machine to do both tasks and Sql server instance is also local to the machine. I see the package starting and executing couple of "Execute SQL Task" correctly. Then when it comes to and "Excel Source" in dataflow, getting this error.

Comment: "To run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher" When your package runs correctly outside of SQL Agent, is this on the same machine that the Agent is installed on?

Comment: @billinkc Yes it's the same machine

Comment: In your Services (Start->Run Services.msc) do you have an entry for "SQL Server Integration Services 10.0"?

Comment: @billinkc Yes that was the issue. The windows service was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking into Services (Start -> Run type `Services.msc`) and revealed that "SQL Server Integration Services 10.0" was not present. This is the SQL Server Integration Services *Service* which provides some validation that this is Server level installation vs a ssdt/bids developer level installation.

Find your SQL Server installation and set about performing a new installation and in the feature install, only install the Integration Services Service.